# Does Fastlane have a default `username`?

Tags: fastlane, fastlane-match

I'm trying to replace a Fastlane Match `username` with a new one on a Mac. No matter what variables I export (MATCH_USERNAME, FASTLANE_USER) or files I edit on my machine (Matchfile), Fastlane keeps picking up a previous user when executing a plain `fastlane match`. If I use the command line `-u` flag to override, then things run perfectly fine.

Does Fastlane have some default username that gets cached on initialization? Is there a way to force this username to be removed or find where it's being ingested by Fastlane (I've tried removing from `fastlane-credentials`, but I'm told it doesn't exist)?

I've got a temporary workaround for the time being, but I wanted to know for future reference.

To recap, I have tried:

- Exporting new `MATCH_USERNAME`,`FASTLANE_USER`
- Editing the `Matchfile` to include the new username
- Removing the account from `fastlane-credentials remove`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "no". Fastlane does not store a default username; however, someone else could set an export in `.bash_profile` that overrides this in a CI pipeline, which is what I just discovered. Mystery solved.